# Magento 2.4: How to hide the Upload button in magento 2 admin?

Tags: file-upload, upload, magento2

We have an image uploader field in Magento 2 admin. When a customer uploads any document in the frontend, the file will be shown in uploader field section. Now what I need is that I want to hide the Upload button in admin and have to restrict admins to upload the attachment from admin portal.

I have tried `visible=false` but its hide the entire section.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is it core Magento or Your custom uploader? Is this menu build in xml? Is it uicomponent? Seems like You want to conditionally `disable` element. Maybe this would be helpful:

https://karnowka.com/posts/magento2-conditional-layout-directives/

It all depends how You build the buttons. Every xml has xsd schema, that means each one has different possibilities but only few allows to conditionally hide element.

Maybe You can use:

```
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
```

or disable element in xml.

Anyway if it's adminhtml I would start looking at xmls.